# Javascript generate n colors that are not random

Tags: javascript, colors, hex, generator, rgb

I have to make sure to generate a color based on a past numeric value.

For example I have the number n must return color (n), `10 -> color (10)`.

So every time I pass the same number, the same color must always come back to me.

There must be no two numbers that give me the same color.

The problem is that I don't know how big this n can be, so I can't define an array of preset colors.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a hex color then you can simply use this two function to convert between them.

```js
var number = parseInt('ffd800', 16);
console.log(number);

var hex = number.toString(16);
console.log(hex)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert RGB into a single integer with a bit of bit shifting..

```
function RGBToInt(red, green, blue){
    let rgb = (red<<8)+green;
        rgb = (rgb<<8)+blue;
    return rgb;
}
```

Since R,G & B are integers from 0 to 255, the final integer will range from 0 to 16777215.
To get the separate R, G & B back from the integer you need to shift the other way

```
function IntToRGB(rgb){
    let colors = {};
    colors.red = (rgb>>16) & 0xFF;
    colors.green = (rgb>>8) & 0xFF;
    colors.blue = rgb & 0xFF;
    return colors;
}
```